# How to setup Typescript inherited classes where subclasses have different properties?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I'm new to Typescript and trying to wrap my head around the best way to handle class inheritance where base classes have some different properties.

Basically, I have a base class for which I want to define some common functionality and a set of subclasses that have different properties as they represent different database models. I'm trying to figure out how to get the types working.

For example:

```
class BaseClass {
  static create(props) { /*... */ }
  update(props) { /*... */ }
}

type SubClassOneProps = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
class SubClassOne extends BaseClass {
  firstName!: string
  lastName!: string
}

type SubClassTwoProps = {
  streetName: string
  streetNumber: number
}
class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass {
  streetName!: string
  streetNumber!: number
}

// I'm looking for typing that will allow me to do the following:
SubClassOne.create({firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Doe"})
SubClassTwo.create({streetName: "Sunset Blvd", streetNumber: 100})

//and then same idea with the instance methods, although I would use Partial<> with these
```

Since the properties are different for each subclass, the signatures vary a bit even though they will all be basic key/value pairs. I don't see how to get the typing right and can't figure out how to specify the properties from the subclasses.

I'm also going to need to store some metadata on each of these properties (specifically, whether they should be publicly accessible or not), and then have an instance method that can export the public properties to a JSON object. But I'll save that as another problem for later.

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Does `static create(props: SubClassOneProps | SubClassTwoProps)` work or is it not generic enough for you? With very few subclasses this might be the easiest option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the advantage of a static `create` over a regular constructor?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMBkZW), maybe? I'm not 100% sure how you plan to associate each XXX class with XXXProps, so I made a guess. If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @Dakeyras - Yes, this would work but for educational purposes I'd like to find the more generic approach

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm using an ORM - objection.js that is setup this way and my base class will actually be extending objection's Model class which is built with this series of statics

Comment: @jcalz Playing around with my linter, this appears to be working! What magic is this that allows the generics to work with the static function? I'm familiar with the different parts of what you did, but it's going to take some mental horsepower for me to work through how the pieces all fit together to make this work.

Comment: I'll write up an answer explaining when I get a chance (it might not be until tomorrow, as it's getting close to bedtime in my time zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main stumbling block here is the lack of [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) on static class members.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for more information.

For instance members, you can use the type named `this` to refer to the "current" subclass:

```
class BaseClass {
  declare test: Array<this>;
}

class SubClassOne extends BaseClass { /* snip */ }
const sc1 = new SubClassOne();
sc1.test // SubClassOne[]

class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass { /* snip */ }
const sc2 = new SubClassTwo();
sc2.test // SubClassTwo[]
```

But there is currently no analog for static members.  For static *methods*, you can use the workaround of making the method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and tying the method's `this` context to the generic type parameter via a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters):

```
class BaseClass {
  declare static test: <T extends BaseClass>(this: new () => T) => Array<T>;
}

class SubClassOne extends BaseClass { /* snip */ }
const sc1t = SubClassOne.test();
// const sc1t: SubClassOne[]

class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass { /* snip */ }
const sc2t = SubClassTwo.test();
// const sc1t: SubClassTwo[]
```

In the above, we're saying that `test()` must be called on a [constructible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) object of type `new () => T`.  When you call `SubClassOne.test()`, the compiler tries to infer `T` from `typeof SubClassOne` being of type `new () => T`, and so `T` is inferred as the instance type, `SubClassOne`.  That's a roundabout way of getting a `this` type from a constructor, but you can do it.

---

So now we have to decide how to associate each subclass with its "props" type, since apparently we need to do that.  I propose making the base class a generic class where the type parameter `T` corresponds to the props type:

```
class BaseClass<T extends object> {
  update(props: T) { Object.assign(this, props) }
}

class SubClassOne extends BaseClass<SubClassOneProps> {
  firstName!: string
  lastName!: string
}
const sc1 = new SubClassOne();
sc1.update({ firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Doe" });

class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass<SubClassTwoProps> {
  streetName!: string
  streetNumber!: number
}
const sc2 = new SubClassTwo();
sc2.update({ streetName: "Sunset Blvd", streetNumber: 100 });
```

Now we can finally declare `create()`:

```
class BaseClass<T extends object> {
  static create<T extends BaseClass<any>>(
    this: { new(): T },
    props: T extends BaseClass<infer U> ? U : never
  ) { const ret = new this(); ret.update(props); return ret; }
}
```

So the `this` context of `create()` has to be a zero-arg constructor producing an instance of generic `T`, and we use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to infer the props type from it.  That is, if `T` is `BaseClass<X>` for some `X`, then `T extends BaseClass<infer U> ? U : never` evaluates to `X`.

Let's test it out:

```
const sc1 = SubClassOne.create({ firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Doe" });
// sc1: SubClassOne
console.log(sc1.firstName.toUpperCase()) // "BOB"

const sc2 = SubClassTwo.create({ streetName: "Sunset Blvd", streetNumber: 100 });
// sc2: SubClassTwo
console.log(sc2.streetNumber.toFixed(2)) // "100.00"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFLIgGwF5oDeoaaksiK6AkmHAC4RioAqAFgJZxEmlrI4IcbgCEhMAMKDhPEHz7149AFxoAggCcNEAJ4AeepzgA+NAF40AbQC6Abl6kAvqAf9p3AMoBXAEZShcADyYOgwAB6KYAAmouL+MsRy8mgAZhwaDABy0DAAhKoMGhxgAOaupNL02bD5aIXFZUlOLk1uAWjefu4sAO4A9mjhkTFoYnCS7rLJdfQaMDBVObX1peUzcwuZXlA+MBq1YNu7Gq7OIC3yyH109HXIAIzmZDA9Hb7xQSEAFACU9q1wB4AOkUDDQAHpwW8ugFgjAbBc+FcbncAExPEKvTofXp9X7-eSA1EgpQQqHY7r9BFJM68cjwJCoDqMegcZDsLhTJGTMYTdqJaYMCCs5BoUEqNB6FiDCIwaKxcYfYxfQxcVSYtC-cymFg-bXqLS6KWmCxasymQ44HC5U6I0gCdoU2EhGXDBV8hJrNIZRY1AqzBprSrVPL+oqrVq01oOmRO4S411yka8j5cwmzea+0PrQOtUiFTNbHZ7A5HPa287R65gwH3W4WOOfGAkhj41yQ-jV261iWNuHU1zImvIVH16E4-ot+ht1odofdh6996UvoDmmI+mUJkePo4Lys65ptoyFPuKWJ+VoPo+ABWMGQ9FMAuSQpF-Dmwpg56GSfdHz0TA6MYyprKQqpwKohDPD0vyqNKjgADSgWgCAaH0CAQWg0o-pep4BHoxQpHsaAAKqmAA-KRaDqjAABu5Z5mgepQfOaBzGOGrgfibELECXgIFEn5fKh6FwH8PH0F4GhgBJthoFG0z8YJijCWhGFwcxaCBLe970ECAQcCUYAqkYCEoWpYnyRWrj0DoCDoH2IQAAoWU8z7yN6WQ5GGubTMG3k5hG8hnJckyOaEsq4XEZ7hS5olPl66ReX6gWNH5QhZssAZBXwCkKHZDnLgEuJxRhblrAWmwBSsaUvhmmxlho6qNRWoWOkV8b9BeybRfhjYlRZCWMZVmU+Tl6YbFUjWlsWJyRi0g5dncjwNh1TZAsgH4qVBnlZqoABEIjXvtZn+bAB0ACJ9DA+3yX87ZQrWqjha4tZ8QJQk7Ule1oIdx2nRlIaXddt2OPdVZ0LuzY4H0JRfG9u0hiCfQkQg9kaBI4i-HqHaHYEIj7XanYokSTz9ZOm0wJ96yFgF+3eHQCyjDgtFRCdNMNbNqj3AADDzd0EnwHZEs9a24q9I7vcpMBfFBI1A79DPjLcIgs2zZny413N8wLi2Qzg0Ow-Dkua7NyMAGIcGEMBRF8qI-DjUL7bzPNAnzhOVoiZyOEAA)

Comment: This works perfectly. Very cool. A few questions: 
1) What's the purpose of `this: { new(): T }` rather than `new() => T`? Does this matter?
2) Why do you say that it has to use a zero-arg constructor? I was able to play around with this and get it working with a constructor with args. Am I missing something? 
3) Lastly, and this is the weird one, if I remove the update method, typing breaks on the create method. After removing the update method, the create method's props changes from SubClassOne to object. What's the relationship here that causes the static method props type to change?

Comment: I'm happy to answer followup questions but if it gets longer than one or two comments they should be moved to their own posts. 1) `{new():T}` and `new()=>T` are interchangeable as far as I know. 2) It doesn't *have* to be a zero-arg constructor, but your examples *were* zero-arg constructors, and my toy implementation calls `new this()` with no arguments.  The implementation of `create()` drives how you give typings to the `this` parameter.

Comment: 3) If the instance type does not depend structurally on `T` [you will have problems with inference](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--). One hopes that your actual classes will *use* any type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a more clean way for a static function than passing a generic to it e.g

```
class BaseClass {
  static create<T>(props: T) {
    /*... */
  }
  update(props) {
    /*... */
  }
}

type SubClassOneProps = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};
class SubClassOne extends BaseClass {
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;
}

type SubClassTwoProps = {
  streetName: string;
  streetNumber: number;
};
class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass {
  streetName!: string;
  streetNumber!: number;
}

SubClassOne.create<SubClassOneProps>({ firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Doe' });
SubClassTwo.create<SubClassTwoProps>({ streetName: 'Sunset Blvd', streetNumber: 100 });
```

In this scenario T is a generic and it's being used as the type of props.

When we're calling SubClassSmth.create({}) we pass in the generic.

If the function wasn't static it could be done in a way cleaner manner e.g assuming create is not static than we could pass in the generic at class level and you wouldn't have to write it again.

```
class BaseClass<U> {
  create(props: U) {
    /*... */
  }
  update(props) {
    /*... */
  }
}

type SubClassOneProps = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};
class SubClassOne extends BaseClass<SubClassOneProps> {
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;
}

type SubClassTwoProps = {
  streetName: string;
  streetNumber: number;
};
class SubClassTwo extends BaseClass<SubClassTwoProps> {
  streetName!: string;
  streetNumber!: number;
}

const subClassOneFactory = new SubClassOne();
const subClassTwoFactory = new SubClassTwo();


subClassOneFactory.create({ firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Doe' });
subClassTwoFactory.create({ streetName: 'Sunset Blvd', streetNumber: 100 });
```

Additional info on why we can't use class-level generics on static functions - [Calling a static function on a generic class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291216/calling-a-static-function-on-a-generic-class-in-typescript)